# Why I get high loss in a very simple 3 layers neural network

Tags: matlab, neural-network, backpropagation, loss-function

For testing something I have implemented this.

I considered a function say: `f(x1,x2)=x1^2+x2^2` with `30` input. using this randomly generated data I want to train the network.
Obviously I have 2 neurons at the input, and 1 neuron at the output. The middle layer has 6 neurons. Also, we have bias in the input and hidden layers.

I have also implemented backpropagation. With the below code I got `0.1` loss which I think is a bit large with the data I have.

Which part I am doing wrong which I get this large loss.

Thanks for your help.